# Screen Brightness on Acer Aspire 5740: bar appears, brightness doesn't change

Tags: boot

Using 23.04 on an Acer Aspire 5740. When I use the function keys to modify screen brightness (or use any solutions I've found here to this problem like the one found here or here), I see the brightness bar appear and change in the top right of my screen, but my actual screen brightness doesn't change.
even i have tried many methods but nothing is working